# OpenGL: Specify what value gets wrote to the depth buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, depth, depth-buffer

As I understand the depth buffer, it calculates a fragment's relation to the far/near clipping planes, and deduces the depth value from that before writing it.  However, this isn't what I want as I don't utilize the clipping planes, or the 3rd dimension at all.  However, depth testing would still be immensely helpful to me.

**My question**, is there any way to specify what value gets written to the depth buffer manually, for all geometry rendered after you set it (that passes the Alpha Test) regardless of it's true depth in a scene?  The Stencil buffer works this way, with the value specified as the second argument of glStencilFunc(), so I thought glDepthFunc() might have behaved similarly but I was mistaken.

The main reason I need depth testing in a 2D game, is because my lighting model uses stencils a great deal.  Objects closer to the camera than the light must be rendered first, for shadow stencils to be properly laid out, with the lights drawn after that.  It's a pretty tricky draw order, but basically it just means lights have to be drawn after the scene is finished drawing, is all.

The OpenGL version I'm using is 2.0, though I'm trying to avoid using a fragment shader if possible.

Comment: can you elaborate why do you want to use this and why this can help you and which openGL version are you using?

Comment: You could use gl_FragDepth.

Comment: concept3d - I updated it!  Sorry for leavin' that info out

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are talking about a technique called [Parallax scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling). You don't need to write to the depth buffer manually, just enable it, and then you can use a layer approach and specify the Z manually for each object. Then render the scene front to back (sorting).

[image]